# Opening files in a parallel loop crash the program

Tags: file, parallel-processing, crash, d

I'm making a simple program in D that loops around the files present inside a given folder and calculate the MD5 of the file. I have got this program working easily with no problem.

I recently learned more about parallelism and thought that my little program would benefit greatly from it.

I changed the loop around the files to a parallel one, but now it is working weird.
The program starts reading files and calculating their MD5, but sometimes, executing close(file) throw an exception with error code 0. Sometimes, there is just an

> Object.Error: Access violation

Sometimes the program just freezes, sometimes it simply crashes.
When I remove the file opening (the loop then basically just print the filename to the console) it works well.

The time it takes for the program to crash is maybe linked to the size of workUnitSize. If not set (default 100), it crashes or stop working after processing around 30-40 files. If I set it to 1, it stops after 2 to 10 files.

Here is the smallest reproducible code I've extracted :

```
import std.md5;
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.conv;
import std.getopt;
import std.string;
import std.process;
import std.parallelism;
import std.exception;
struct Entry
{
    string name;
    ubyte[16] md5;
}
int ChunkStep = 4096;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string folder1 = args[1];
    string folder2 = args[2];

    Entry[] entries1;
    foreach (name; parallel(dirEntries(folder1, SpanMode.breadth), 1)) // not working
    {
        if(name.isFile())
        {
            entries1 ~= Entry(name ,mdFile(name));
        }

    }

    writeln(folder1," has ",entries1.length, " entries");
    Entry[] entries2;
    foreach (string name; dirEntries(folder2, SpanMode.breadth)) //working fine
    {
        if(name.isFile())
        {
            entries2 ~= Entry(name ,mdFile(name));
        }
    }
    writeln(folder2," has ", entries2.length, " entries");
}
/// Digests a file and prints the result.
ubyte[16] mdFile(string filename)
{
    MD5_CTX context;
    ubyte[16] digest;
    context.start();
    File f = File(filename,"r");

    foreach (buffer; f.byChunk(ChunkStep))
        context.update(buffer);

    context.finish(digest);
    try{
        f.close();
    }
    catch(ErrnoException e)
    {
        writeln(e.errno);
    }
    writefln("MD5 (%s) = %s", filename, digestToString(digest));
    return digest;
}
```

I'm using Dmd2.064.2 on Windows 7 64b with a Intel Q6600 (quad core).

Answer (score 1):

Do you use 32bit version of dmd?

**update:**
seems on windows there is some bug with byChunk (rawRead). So you can use std.stream instead.

```
import std.md5;
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.conv;
import std.getopt;
import std.string;
static import std.stream;
import std.process;
import std.parallelism;
import std.exception;

struct Entry
{
    string name;
    ubyte[16] md5;
}
enum ChunkStep = 4096;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string folder1 = args[1];
    string folder2 = args[2];

    Entry[] entries1;
    foreach (name; parallel(dirEntries(folder1, SpanMode.breadth), 1)) // not working
    {
        if(name.isFile())
        {
            entries1 ~= Entry(name ,mdFile(name));
        }

    }

    writeln(folder1," has ",entries1.length, " entries");
}
/// Digests a file and prints the result.
ubyte[16] mdFile(string filename)
{
    MD5_CTX context;
    ubyte[16] digest;
    context.start();
    std.stream.File f = new std.stream.File(filename);
    byte[ChunkStep] buffer;
    size_t len;

    while((len = f.readBlock(buffer.ptr, ChunkStep)) > 0) {
        context.update(buffer.ptr[0 .. len]);
    }

    context.finish(digest);
    f.close();
    writefln("MD5 (%s) = %s", filename, digestToString(digest));
    return digest;
}
```

Comment: can you please try compile it with -m32 option if anything change. I try it on my machine but I have linux and everything seems to ok here

Comment: Yes, I was using the default 32bit compile mode. After trying with -m64, it works good. Any Idea why this doesn't work on 32bit ? It works perfectly without the parallel loop.

Comment: @Orygin I am not sure but when I looked into phobos sources I find out there is some different stdio function for 32bit and 64bit on windows platform. https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/stdio.d#L30 . So I think it is a BUG, so it would be fine if you will post bug report on https://d.puremagic.com/issues/

Comment: Alright. I will do that. I suspected a bug related to D but wanted to have confirmation it was not my code at fault.

Comment: I just reported the bug at https://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11862 . Thank you for helping me.